# Pasar una imagen a una etiquete img/src

Tags: c#, html5, razor

Trabajo con Visual Studio 2015, C#, Windows Forms
Tengo una imagen que es un logo en la base de datos, en la base de datos la tengo como byte.
Cuando recupero la imagen de la db esta en byte pero lo puedo convertir a imagen.

La necesidad que tengo es pasar una ruta que contiene una imagen a este html.

```
<img src="D:\PruebasCSharp\CrearReportePDF\CrearReportePDF\Imagenes\logo.jpeg"
                                                     height="90"
                                                     width="230" />
```

Lo que puedo hacer es, al momento que la traigo de la db convertirla a imagen y luego guardarla en una ruta y pasarle esa ruta a la etiqueta img.

¿Se podrá pasarle la imagen directamente al img?

Cuando le paso datos al html es por medio de razor

```
<img src=@Model.RutaLogo
                                                     height="90"
                                                     width="230" />

_rutaLogo = Convert.ToBase64String(configuracion.Logo);
```

Caundo convierto a pdf

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(result);
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            var htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc); //ITextSharp hace la magia
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();

                htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                pdfDoc.Close();

                byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                memoryStream.Close();

                var testFile = @"D:\\test.pdf";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(testFile, bytes);

                var resultCorreo = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(templateCorreo, "Key2", null, model);
                Utilidades.EnviarMail("minimainor_austin@hotmail.com", "pavilan154@gmail.com", "Hola", resultCorreo, "xxxxx", testFile);
            }
```

Me da error en htmlparser.

> Error: La ruta de acceso especificada o el nombre de archivo (o ambos)
>   son demasiado largos. El nombre de archivo completo debe ser inferior
>   a 260 caracteres y el nombre del directorio debe ser inferior a 248.

El string del logo es demasiado grande.

Mostrando logo en el html, bueno no me alcanza lo pondré como imagen
[image: logo]

No logro salir todo en la imagen, jejeje...

Comment: Tendrías que convertir el contenido de la imagen a base64 y ponerlo dentro de `src` como un tipo data. [Ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html).

Comment: @Andrew Ya lo hice, pero como estoy creando un pdf por medio del html me da error. Lo voy a publicar.

Comment: No entiendo, ¿qué tiene que ver la ruta del archivo? ¿Probaste que el html esté bien antes de meterte con el tema de la conversión a PDF?

Comment: @Andrew la conversión funciona muy bien si le quito la imagen pasada como un string en base 64 el problema me parece que no lo renderiza ya que no lo ejecuta como web, mejor lo voy a poner la imagen en una ruta y tomarla de ahí igual voy a publicar como llega la imagen al html.

Comment: Porque no hiciste como explica en el link; pusiste el base64 directo. Tienes que poner `data:image/jpeg;base64,` y luego tu código. El espacio tras la coma no afecta.

Comment: @Andrew la verdad no me había fijado que habías puesto un enlace si el espacio no afecta me sale un error  "No se reconoce el prefijo URI"

Comment: Me da un mensaje de caracteres no validos en la ruta de acceso, sera por nunca lo voy a renderizar ya que es una app de escritorio. el no reconoce la imagen el piensa que le estoy pasando una ruta de acceso.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos amigo ya casi lo tenías, solo te falta especificar el tipo de datos en el src. Si mapeaste como byte[] la propiedad de tu modelo, puedes utilizar el método Convert.ToBase64String y posteriormente indicar el formato en la propiedad "src" de la siguiente forma:

```
                @{
                    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Imagen); //La propiedad de tu modelo que es byte[]
                    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64); // Damos formato para indicar que se trata de una cadena base64
                }

                <img src="@imgSrc" width="80" height="80" />
```

Ahora, este enfoque no te servirá en Winforms, pero si quisieras hacerlo, podrías hacer eso de una artillería que me ha servido bastante.

```
public static class UtilidadesByte
{
    public static byte[] ConvertirImagenAByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

    public static System.Drawing.Image ConvertirByteArrayAImagen(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

}

Es importante que sepas que tienes que importar la liberaría System.Drawing a tu proyecto para que te pueda funcionar (Claro, en caso que no la tuvieras ya importada con anterioridad):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos

Comment: La imagen tiene esta cadena: data:image/gif;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ... y me da el siguiente error: No se reconoce el prefijo URI

Comment: Me parece falta un espacio al costado de la coma

Comment: Creo que el espacio no influye, al menos en mis pruebas. Y recuerda que es jpg, no gif.

Comment: @Andrew tienes razón el espacio no influye en nada lo acabo de probar en html y funciona excelente, pero en mi app de Windows Forms no funciona.

Comment: En Windows Forms tendría que ser diferente la solución. Editaré mi publicación.

Answer (score 0):

La única solución fue obtener la imagen desde la base de datos en byte y luego convertirla a un objeto Image para luego guardarla en bin/debug, para luego utilizar la ruta para enviarselo como parámetro al html.

```
var logo = ImageHelper.ByteArrayToImage(configuracion.Logo);
            var pathLogo = Application.StartupPath + "\\mylogo.jpg";
            logo.Save(pathLogo);
            _rutaLogo = pathLogo;
```

Saludos!